# Using GNU Make for Script Building

Tags: scripting, vbscript, makefile

I have a script (the language is VBScript, but for the sake of the question, it's unimportant) which is used as the basis for a number of other scripts -- call it a "base script" or "wrapper script" for others.  I would like to modularize my repository so that this base script can be combined with the functions unique to a specific script instance and then rebuilt later, should either one of the two change.

Example:

- `baseScript.vbs` -- Logging, reporting, and other generic functions.
- `queryServerFunctions.vbs` -- A script with specific, unique tasks (functions) that depend on functions in `baseScript.vbs`.

I would like to use `make` to combine the two (or any arbitrary number of files with script fragments) into a single script -- say, `queryServer.vbs` -- that is entirely self-contained.  This self-contained script could then be rebuilt by `make` anytime either of its source scripts changes.

The question, then, is: Can I use `make` to manage script builds and, if so, what is the best or preferred way of doing so?

If it matters, my scripting environment is Cygwin running on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of VBScript and GNU make is unusual, so I doubt you'll find a "preferred way" of doing this. It is certainly possible. Taking your example, and adding another script called `fooServer.vbs` to show how the solution works for multiple scripts, here's a simple makefile:

```
# list all possible outputs here
OUTPUT := queryServer.vbs fooServer.vbs

# tell make that the default action should be to produce all outputs
.PHONY: all
all: $(OUTPUT)

# generic recipe for combining scripts together
$(OUTPUT):
        cat $+ > $@
# note: The first character on the line above should be a tab, not a space

# now we describe the inputs for each output file
queryServer.vbs: baseScript.vbs queryServerFunctions.vbs
fooServer.vbs: baseScript.vbs fooFunctions.vbs
```

That will create the two scripts for you from their inputs, and if you touch, for example `queryServerFunctions.vbs` then only `queryServer.vbs` will be remade.

Why go to all that trouble, though?

The purpose of `make` is to "rebuild" things efficiently, by comparing file timestamps to judge when a build step can be safely skipped because the inputs have not changed since the last time the output file was updated. The assumption is that build steps are expensive, so it's worth skipping them where possible, and the performance gain is worth the risk of skipping too much due to bugs in the makefile or misleading file timestamps.

For copying a few small files around, I would say a simple batch file like

```
copy /y baseScript.vbs+queryServerFunctions.vbs queryServer.vbs
copy /y baseScript.vbs+fooServerFunctions.vbs fooServer.vbs
```

would be a better fit.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply.  I was curious if `make` is capable of more complex operations than simple concatenation; I understand it was primarily designed for compile languages, but I wondered if perhaps it were possible to interleave files in a more sophisticated way than `a.vbs + b.vbs = c.vbs` -- perhaps with includes or something similiar.

Comment: `make` itself can't do that: It's designed to drive other programs that operate on files (historically: C compilers). In my example, the program it's driving is `cat`.

Comment: You could replace `cat` in the makefile with something more sophisticated: Another VBScript, perhaps, or, for maximum weirdness, the C preprocessor: `cat $+ | gcc -E - >$@` would allow you to use commands like `#include` in the input files. But again, unless these transformations get *very* expensive, I'd stick with a simple batch file or script.